# Pandas GroupBy Object : What is it?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Is the Pandas GroupBy object an iterator? or an instance of a generator?

If its an iterator its not getting exhausted?
I tried the below to find

```
#pivot1 = df.groupby('Invoices', as_index=False)[['Invoices','InvAmt']]

import inspect
inspect.isgeneratorfunction(pivot1) #False

import types
isinstance(pivot1, types.GeneratorType) #False
```

Comment: It is neither. It is merely *iterable*. It is not an iterator. See what it says when you do `nex(pivot1)`

Comment: ya got `TypeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object is not an iterator`...so how to take this groupby, as its not storing result in memory like generator but from `next(pivot1)` its obvious its not iterator...if its iterable im not able to do slicing or get elements from index

Comment: Not all iterables need to be indexable/sliceable.... They just need to implement `__iter__`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oh wow :) Thank you ...enlightened now